# Sending an email using Exchange Web Services on behalf of a distribution group

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, distribution-list

I have an email account with exchange, i can send and receive emails from that account's email.

This account is a member of a distribution list, i want to be able to send the replies from this account with the address of the distribution list (on behalf of).
I tried to set the Email.From property and that made no difference
I tried to set the Email.Sender property and it gave me at error that this property cannot be changed although it is a set and get.

The account does have permissions to send on behalf of the distribution list.

Please any ideas?

Regards
Yazeed

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using ? For a distribution list you won't be able to Send On Behalf but you should be able to SendAs so you need to give the account SendAs rights on the list and Set the From Address and that should work okay.

Comment: Thank you Glen for your response, as it appears, the problem was with replicating the permissions between domains, the account i was using had rights to send on behalf only that permission was not replicated around the network so the nod i was using was not aware of it. it is now working!